# Encrypt REST Response Stream with Yii 2.0

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

I want to encrypt the response stream of a REST-Request. I fetch the data from the db and return it as xml (actionAll). This works fine. Then I added an eventHandler that is executed before the response is sent to the client (beforeAction). This works too.  My problem is, that the **$response** within the **encryptResponse**-method does not contain any data, when the eventHandler calls it. The variables content, data and stream are always null within the response-object.

Thanks for any help!

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Order;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
use yii\web\Response;
use app\models\User;

class OrderController extends \yii\rest\Controller{

    /**
    * disable session for REST-Request
    * no loginUrl required  
    */
     public function init(){
        parent::init();
        \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
        \Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = null;
    }

   /**
    * HttpBasicAuth for authentication  
    */
    public function behaviors(){
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        'auth'  => function ($username, $password) {
            if($username==\Yii::$app->params['HttpBasicAuth']['username'] &&     $password==\Yii::$app->params['HttpBasicAuth']['password']){
                return new User();
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }];
        return $behaviors;
    }

   /**
    * set response-format to xml
    * fetch data from db
    *   
    */
    public function actionAll(){
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;
        $models = Order::find()->all(); 
        return $models;
    }

   /**
    * hook into action and add event handler    
    */
    public function beforeAction($action){      
        $response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
        $response->on(Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND, [$this, 'encryptResponse']);
    }

   /**
    * callback for event-handler    
    */
    public function encryptResponse(){
        $response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
        var_dump($response);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your response event in the init.

Or you just have to add `return true` in your `beforeAction` function, otherwise data will be `null` because the action isn't called, this is also mentioned in the Yii2 docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction%28%29-detail).

```
use Yii;

...

public function init() 
{
    parent::init();

    Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
    Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = null;
    Yii::$app->response->on(Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND, [$this, 'encryptResponse']);
}

public function beforeAction($action)
{      
    $response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
    $response->on(Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND, [$this, 'encryptResponse']);

    return true; // << required
}
```